# Django ModelForm not saving data even though form.save is executed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a website where user have 2 model for their profile, user_detail and user_location. I tried to serve 2 model form on one page with one submit. The problem is when the data from those model form does not save in to the database.

I confirmed that self.request.POST in the post method returns the correct data.

I tried :

[Django ModelForm not saving data to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284010/django-modelform-not-saving-data-to-database) - Does not work

[Django ModelForm not saving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689235/django-modelform-not-saving-data) - Does not work

The following code if for admins.

Here is my view :

```
class UpdateProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'account/user_profile.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    model = models.UserProfile
    user_detail_form_class = forms.UserDetailForm
    user_location_form_class = forms.UserLocationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(models.UserProfile, pk=self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg))

        context = super(UpdateProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'user_detail_form' not in context:
            context['user_detail_form'] = self.user_detail_form_class(instance=user_profile.user_detail)
        if 'user_location_form' not in context:
            context['user_location_form'] = self.user_location_form_class(instance=user_profile.user_location)

        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateProfile, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_detail_form = self.user_detail_form_class(request.POST)
        user_location_form = self.user_location_form_class(request.POST)

        if user_detail_form.is_valid() and user_location_form.is_valid():
            user_detail_form.save()
            user_location_form.save()
            return redirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('account:admin_client_list')

        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Admin']).exists():
                 return errors.render_403(request)

            return super(UpdateProfile, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my template :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method='POST' action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_detail_form }}
    {{ user_location_form }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the form :

```
class UserDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserDetail
        fields = '__all__'


class UserLocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserLocation
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: What do your forms do? Create or update? Is there any foreign key relationship?

Comment: It updates. Hence UpdateProfile. No foreignkey relationships. I have to say though these 2 models are bound to another model called UserProfile by onetoonekeys.

Comment: I guess you need to pass the `instance` parameter during `ModelForm` creation. e.g. something like `self.user_detail_form_class(request.POST, instance=user_profile)`

Comment: you mean on the POST method?

Comment: Yes. you need to write `user_detail_form = self.user_detail_form_class(request.POST, instance=user_profile.user_detail)` in your post method. `user_profile` can be found by `user_profile = get_object_or_404(models.UserProfile, pk=self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg))` as before

Comment: Thank you for the help! If you write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I should have realised that I customized the UpdateView so getting the right model instance should also be specified.

Comment: I've posted the answer. Glad to know your problem has been solved. Happy Coding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167785/discussion-between-nayan-and-kuo-chong-yii).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `instance` parameter when you are creating the `ModelForm` in the post method. Sample code:

```
user_profile = get_object_or_404(models.UserProfile, pk=self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg))
user_detail_form = self.user_detail_form_class(request.POST, instance=user_profile.user_detail)
user_location_form = self.user_location_form_class(request.POST, instance=user_profile.user_location)
```